# app:dexDebug ExecException finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In libs is one *.jar file.

- Sync: OK
- Make Project: OK
- Clean: OK
- Run: Error
  Error:
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   
>   My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'StarPhone Signing Key'
            keyPassword 'star2star'
            storeFile file('../signingKey.jks')
            storePassword 'star2star'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.6.2"
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        buildConfigField "long", "TIMESTAMP", System.currentTimeMillis() + "L"
        buildConfigField "int", "PJSIP_LOG_LEVEL", "4"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        debug {
        }
        monkeytalk.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        monkeytalk {
            applicationIdSuffix ".monkey"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(project(':fonticon')) {
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    monkeytalkCompile fileTree(dir: 'monkey-libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: I know an answer. It's too many process(seeing your Gradle logs). Turn on ProGuard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on ProGuard because it's too many process (over 65K). See [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)